# If I use Objective C 2.0's @synthesize, does that mean my model class is KVC compliant (including validation)?

Tags: objective-c

1) Or do I still need to implement to validation methods described in the KVC guide?
and
2) do I need to override the setNilValueForKey: and similar methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joris, what I mean is do I need to declare -(BOOL)validateName:(id)newValue error:(NSError **)outError for each of my property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is KVO compliant if you use `@synthesize`.

But it will not have any validation. The run-time can not make any guess on how you want to validate your data. So `nil` values etc. will be allowed. Validation is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "including validation"?

But indeed, your class is KVC compliant for the properties you declare as such